# Filter on a collection using a List containing arguments

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection of Customers containing CustomerId, CustomerName and a few other columns.

I'm passing in a list of Ids to filter the collection.

This is how far I'ver got - in this example 'filteredCustomers' should contain Customers having a customerId of 3 or 5.

```
List<int> customerIds = new List<int>();
customerIds.Add(3);
customerIds.Add(5);

var filteredCustomers = from Customer in Customers.Where(x=>x.CustomerId).Contains(customerIds);
```

What am I doing wrong - any help greatly appreciated.

Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
var filteredCustomers = Customers.Where(x => customerIds.Contains(x.CustomerId));
```

However, I would strongly recommend using a `HashSet<T>` instead of `List<T>` for this, as it will make the `Contains` check dramatically faster if you add more numbers in the future.  This would look like:

```
var customerIds = new HashSet<int>();
customerIds.Add(3);
customerIds.Add(5);

var filteredCustomers = Customers.Where(x => customerIds.Contains(x.CustomerId));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from Customer in Customers
where customerIDs.Contains(Customer.CustomerId);
```

Comment: and you can inline the list: from Customer in Customers where new List<int> { 3, 5 }.Contains(Customer.CustomerId)

Comment: I believe you will need a `select Customer` clause at the end.

Comment: true, but he didn't have a select and so I omitted it from mine as well: from Customer in Customers where new List<int> { 3, 5 }.Contains(Customer.CustomerId) select Customer;

Answer (score 1):

```
var filteredCustomers = Customers.Where(x=>customerIds.Contains(x.CustomerId));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var byCustIds = from d in Customers
                where customerIDs.Contains(d.CustomerId)
                select d;
```